# Open WordPress day archive via javascript

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm working at a WP plugin that will show jquery-ui datepicker in the site home page. Everything seems work well except that I'm not able to open the archive link of the selected day from javascript. Is there a way to open day archive from JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url of the archive day will depend on your permalink structure. However, you can consistently link to a url like this:
/wordpress/?day=29&monthnum=11&year=2011

If the site is using permalinks, that url will redirect to the correct permalink (for example /2011/11/29/ in this case).

Does that answer your question?

Comment: thank you very much, chmac! It seems to work well. I've made some tests and I've noticed that the structure you suggest works well, and WP redirects to /siteurl/year/month/day. 
I can show my jQuery UI date-picker now :-)

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working, I thought I'd get an email if somebody replied, so I'm only seeing your comment now. Thanks for accepting my first answer on SO. :-)